# Testing fixtures for attributes with class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

In rails, a model

```
belongs_to :production_variety, class_name: 'Categoryminor'
```

the fixtures for categoryminors.yml has an entry

```
production_mel_lung:
  id: 113
```

Yet, when running a test whether any of the following is provided for a fixture in this model's class

```
one:
  production_variety: production_mel_lung.id

one:
  production_variety: production_mel_lung

one:
  production_variety_id: 113
```

for the unit test

```
culture = cultures(:one)
assert culture.valid?, culture.errors.full_messages.inspect
```

invariably returns

```
["Production variety must exist"]
```

Which is incorrect given the model definition.  What must be done syntaxically to the fixtures to make this a proper test?

Comment: this syntax is correct -- `production_variety: production_mel_lung`. Are you sure you are loading the fixtures in the test?  If you add `puts Categoryminors.all` before the assert what spits out?  The id in the fixture is a bit odd -- that is usually autogenerated  from the label.  Could be that rails is having a hard time creating the categoryminors record because of the specified id.

Comment: Interesting catch.  the `puts`  generates `NameError: uninitialized constant CultureTest::Categoryminors`  Why is the test not cogniscent of the model definition? *note* The id is in the fixture as a mental anchor (it is part of a set of data that will be used in reality)  the question was amended for the test is attempted run with the `production_variety_id` being invoked.

Comment: Could be a name conflict causing the loading issue -- but the id change won't work unless that id actually exists in the test data

Comment: the class name is assigned to Categoryminor, but could the test be expecting a `production_varieties.yml` fixture?

Comment: Unlikely, but you can try it.

Comment: Figured it out.  production_variety was a red herring.  only upon asking in the test `puts Categoryminor.all.pluck(:id)` did I see that 113 was missing for rails, although defined in the fixture file. Two fixtures had an identical name, thus the former one was ignored.